# How to automatically remove GitLab runners in Web UI that are no longer available due to Kubernetes pod no longer available

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I have deployed my own small private Kubernetes cluster and in it I have deployed a GitLab agent with (currently) a single pod with a runner inside that handles my playground CICD pipeline (learning about cloud tech and CICD at the same time). Since I am currently running my cluster in a VM on my laptop I do shut down my cluster whenever I've finished working for the day.

After shutdown once started, the cluster automatically deploys a new pod with the GitLab runner. The agent picks it up and sends that information to the GitLab instance, which respectively offers it to the respective project(s).

Below you can see an example for this situation:

[image: GitLab runners provided by K8s pods]

The bottom runner is no longer available (pod was destroyed). The one on top is the new pod that was launched automatically by the cluster.

While currently this is manageable, I am thinking about the future. If I kill the pod 10 times for some reason (or it gets redeployed due to e.g. a crash), I will get 10 inactive runners in the list and one active (the latest one). 10 runners that will never ever be again (unless by some coincidence the cluster creates a runner with the exact same ID).

I was unable to find any information in the GitLab documentation and the menus in the Web UI. I am also aware that my approach is probably very crude and can be optimized (suggestions are welcomed!).

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of a few things.

### Preserve the runner token

When you register the runner, you use the registration token (static) to obtain a runner token (unique to each runner). This token is written to the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file. This is also the part of the process that creates a new runner entry in your runner list. It appears you are registering new runners every time you 'redeploy' your runners.

If you preserve your `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file (e.g., by mounting the `/etc/gitlab-runner` directory as a volume for each runner container) then you will reuse the same runner token whenever you shutdown and bring up your runner and therefore will reuse the same runner/ID upon redeployment.

### Cleanup offline runners

If a runner does not make contact with the GitLab server for some time, it will be marked as "Offline". You can [list the runners for your group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#list-groups-runners) using the API (you can also filter on `status=offline`) and then use the API to [delete a runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#delete-a-runner) using the ID(s) returned by your first query.

You can extract this logic into a script and run it periodically (or, perhaps, even from a scheduled GitLab pipeline).

---

Be aware, GitLab plans to [deprecate registration tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/token_overview.html#runner-registration-tokens-deprecated) in favor of 'runner authentication tokens' starting in GitLab version 16.0 (not yet released) and plans to remove registration tokens in version 17.0 -- so this advice may become stale within the next couple years.